# indexedDB updating api files stored

Tags: indexeddb

Curious if how i am implementing the use of indexedDB correctly.
I use it to cache several json files data from a 3rd party API.
Some of the json files need updated every 5 minutes to get new data from the API , so i put a timestamp on the files stored in indexedDB and if the file timestamp is older then 5 minutes , the next user page refresh , a new call to the api is made to retrieve latest file.
Is this the only and/or correct way to handle this ?  I have not seen any method of refreshing or updating the stored data in indexedDB that would automate this process without using some sort of timestamp.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Periodic_Background_Synchronization_API might be helpful

Comment: Thanks, the browser support is no bueno